# Estructuras condicionales if, elif y else

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones, booleano

En mi curso de matemáticas me están enseñando esto de las Estructuras condicionales y condición, pero por más que intento entender no entiendo **la diferencia y cuando es que es adecuado utilizarlo**. Me refiero al if, elif y else. (Python) alguien me lo puede explicar sin terminos tan dificiles.

Lo que más no entiendo es **¿porque no simplemente se pueden remplazar el elif con otro if, y para lo demás else?**

¿Aparte creo que también existe algo que se llama **if not**, no sé si tenga algo que ver con esto de las condicionales o no, pero entonces no tendría **el mismo significado de elif en inglés**?

¿También cuál es la relación con los datos booleanos?

La verdad es que no se dé esto de programación pero supongo que es necesario para las matemáticas, lo siento si no se me entendió bien o algo así.

Comment: Hola, mírate la pregunta duplicada a ver si resuelve tu primera duda. En cuanto al resto, `not` es un operador lógico unario de negación, simplemente niega a su operando, `not True` retorna `False` y `not False` retorna `True`, por ejemplo `not 4 > 3` retorna `False`. Aunque se ve comúnmente en condicionales es independiente de ellos, no hay un `if not` como tal, realmente es `if (not algo)`. Debes limitar tu pregunta a una duda concreta, mírate [ask] y [tour] para conocer mejor el sitio, por cierto bienvenid@ a [es.so].